# Table with headers in first column

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Can tableView table in JavaFx 8 have headers in first column? With sortability and other functionality. How can it be set?

For better understanding what I am asking I found this picture:

[image]

EDIT:

(Upper image is not connected to code)

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> personTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;


private void fillTable() {
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

    personTable.setItems(PersonData);
}
```

This code snippet is from controller class where tableView is filled with data. Headers are set using SceneBuilder. If I run this as it is, header will be in first row. Can I somehow set orientation of headers or something so table would behaviour as columns were rows and reverse?

Comment: Have you tried something like [googled a bit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+table+javafx+with+sortable+headers) and write some lines of code??

Comment: I googled and found nothing. Your google link would point me out to classic tables, which I know of. Problem is placement of headers in first column, not first row....